# How to jump to the region header from the endregion tag in c# visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, region

If i have the following

```
#region
blah;
blahblah;
.....
moar;
#endregion
```

how can i jump to the top #region label if i see the #endregion tag on my screen?

Is there a short cut?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> as already answered by @TheEvilPenguin.

But I thought to add this [**awesome link**](https://www.dofactory.com/visual-studio-shortcuts) for other shortcuts as well, which can be helpful in speeding up routine tasks in VS.

Save the link page as html in your system, as the link might expire in future.

Comment: @Boppity Bop update VS 2015 to Update 2 and it is working again for VS 2015 as well.

Comment: yes now it works. I had to write to MS.. perhaps it helped ;)

Comment: the "awesome link" is dead

Comment: @Tom667 thank you! Updated the rotten link with the latest. It seems their site went through an upgrade.

Answer (score 26):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> will jump between the start and end of blocks.  I just tested, and it works for #region blocks for me in VS2010.

Edit:  The relevant command is [Edit.GoToBrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#editors)

Comment: Alt+Up, Alt+Down has the same concept. I find it more comfortable.

Comment: In my VS2010 that moves the current line up/down one.  It may have changed for 2012 though.

Comment: Oh, it might be a ReSharper shortcut... Recommended in any case.

Comment: control + ] will work for regions as well as any opening curly brackets to closing curly brackets and vice versa.

Comment: Works for VS2015 SP3. Please note that this works only if you click on the word region (or endregion)

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I was able to figure out on Visual Studio for Mac (7), is seemed to default to Shift + Cmd + \

Answer (score 23):

For Visual Studio 2015, `Ctrl + ]` doesn't work anymore. But you can use the following:

1. Click on `region`
2. And use following shortcuts: `Ctrl + shift + ↑` and `Ctrl + shift + ↓`

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. With a future update of VS 2015, this issue will be fixed. There is an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7120) for that which is already resolved, so it's just a matter of when the next milestone will be published.

Comment: Let me clarify. Hovering will not do. you need to click on the very word (region or endregion) for this workaround to work. (VS2015SP3)

Comment: Still works on Visual Studio 2019 (v16.11.3) too!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a standard shortcut in Visual Studio.

Within Visual Studio's options dialog, I did a search through all available commands for anything containing the word "region":

[image: Region commands]

But didn't find anything related to navigation, just expand/collapse.

Addins like [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) may give you what you want, if you have the budget for it. (And they do a lot more besides.)