# Find the start of a #region

Tags: c#, visual-studio, region

I have a huge page of code, I was scrolling up and came across #endregion: hoping to quickly find the start of this I pressed F12 on it. No luck.

Is there/what is the best way to basically jump from start to end of a defined region? (collapsing obviously doesn't let you read the contents)

Comment: `CTRL` + `]` should do the trick. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521604/how-to-jump-to-the-region-header-from-the-endregion-tag-in-c-sharp-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>.

Here are some other useful shortcuts using #region:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - This collapses or expands the current region
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Collapse or expand all regions in the document **recursively**
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Collapse all regions not recursively

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, going from memory...

> Ctrl + ]

Comment: Whoops, looks like nolegs beat me to it.  Glad to see my memory didn't fail, at least.